# Update text box when user selects a particular option

Tags: validation, update, inputformtextbox

The user has the option [Approve] [Reject] at the approval stage.
It is a choice radio option and I like to update the `Comment` box to say `I have Approved this request` when the choice [Approve] has been ticked.

I have looked around and trying to put something together, but I am having not much luck.

```
NWF$(document).ready(function(){
 NWF$("#"+ddlContentType).change(function()
 {
var selectedValue = NWF$('#' + ddlContentType).find("input:checked").siblings("label").text() == "Approve";
NWF$("#"+txtAppendix).val("I have Approved this request");
 });
});
```

JavaScript variable names: 
`ddlContentType` is the Choice with the Approve or Reject option.
`txtAppendix` is the Comment box where I like it to update.

The above script, updates the CommentBox, a soon as an option is selected. The idea behind is to update the CommentBox only when Approve option is selected otherwise it needs to remain blank.

Any advise?
I am a neewbie at scripting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, you're just not actually checking to see IF the selected value is approved or not, and *only then* take action.  Since you never actually check IF the condition you want is there, then the line of code that adds the statement to the text box *always* executes.

This line here

```
var selectedValue = NWF$('#' + ddlContentType).find("input:checked").siblings("label").text() == "Approve";
```

is a little misleading because the variable name is `selectedValue`, which *sounds* like it should be equal to either "Approve" or "Reject" (i.e. the selected value), and it *would* be if the line ended at `.text()`.  But since you added `== 'Approve'` at the end, then really `selectedValue` is going to be `true` or `false`.

You could work with that, and just check

```
if (selectedValue === true) {
    // if it's true, it means the selected option label equals "Approve", as per that line above
}
```

but I'm not a fan of misleading variable names, so I would recommend restructuring a little bit to make it more clear what you are actually checking:

```
NWF$(document).ready(function () {
    NWF$("#" + ddlContentType).change(function () {
        
        // get the text value of the label of the selected option
        var selectedValue = NWF$('#' + ddlContentType).find("input:checked").siblings("label").text();

        // check to see if that does equal "Approve"
        if (selectedValue === "Approve") {

            // if it does, add your statement to the text box
            NWF$("#" + txtAppendix).val("I have Approved this request");

        } else {

            // if it does NOT, then clear the text box,
            // in case someone accidentally clicked on "Approve" and
            // added the statement, but then changed their mind
            NWF$("#" + txtAppendix).val("");

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I couldn't have done it better :) thank you for your advise and support.